# Bootstrap modal not displaying image when clicked jquery script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, instagram

I have a script displaying some images from instagrams api. When and image or video is clicked I would like it to display in the bootstrap modal. I have the modal displaying but I dont know how to connect the part of the image or video to show in the modal body. I am not very advanced with javascript/jQuery and cant seem to figure it out. I have searched a lot of other scenarios but nothing that was quite like what I am trying to do. I have pieced this script together with the help of a friend who is quite a bit more advanced with writing scripts with api's. In the end I'm trying to show likes comments from the clicked image/video in the modal. Here is my page with complete code. I removed my client_id and access_token. http://pastebin.com/vjckgeyL

Comment: provide some code so that we can help you. otherwise we will not write code for you

Comment: I included a pastebin link in my question that has the complete code.

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: I just clicked it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initiated modal.

add `$('#myModal').modal();` or `$('#myModal').modal({ options });`
 at the bottom of your script.

[more about bootstrap modal APIs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: I dont know how to implement that correctly. I dont know what options to pass. (I am not very good with jquery) - I have read the docs you posted before posting my question. They didnt help anything click to fix my issue.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer probably you need to learn more basics & help from your friend :)  But the above is the answer.

Comment: may I ask what option do I pass?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer just add `$('#myModal').modal();` before last `</script>`

Comment: Its now popping up the modal on page load. And its not putting the linking image into the modal when clicked. [demo here](http://instagram.claytonmiller.com/)

Comment: you are passing `gram.images.standard_resolution.url` in image source, it will not work, you have to pass it within the script & push it.

Comment: I realize that I need to pass it within the script. But dont know how to write that. Is there any sample code within jquery documentation on this type of function? Sometimes its hard for me to find things when I dont know the correct terminology to search by. So far nothing suggested has helped my code. Just passing the HTML5 data-attribute is enough to trigger the modal. Javascript usage is just an option. My modal already opened before. Just didnt function as intended. I will gladly upvote or mark answered if it helps. I do appreciate your time helping me this far!